# How to read AWS S3 images from Sagemaker for processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I have around 10000 images in my S3 bucket. I need to cut each of these images to 12 smaller images and save them in another folder in the S3 bucket. I want to do this through the AWS Sagemaker. I am not able to read the image from the S3 bucket from my Sagemaker Jupter notebook. I have the code for cutting the images.

Need help in reading images and storing them back into S3 from Sagemaker.Is it possible to do this, and also efficiently?

Comment: Could you please edit your question to provide more information, such as what you've tried so far and what difficulties you are encountering? If you have the code already, why can't you use it?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Please check now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bring images to a local repo of your SageMaker instance (eg /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Pics/ with the following command:

```
aws s3 sync s3://pic_folder_in_s3 /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Pics
```

or in python:

```
import subprocess as sb

sb.call('aws s3 sync s3://pic_folder_in_s3 /home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Pics'.split())
```

Note that in order for the transfer to happen, the role carried by your SageMaker instance must have the right to read from this S3 location